# Expanding subviews in scrollview on tapping

Tags: iphone, gridview, uiscrollview, expand

I am trying to expand the subviews in a uiscrollview on tapping, exactly like how the twitter #music app does.I am confused with the flow calculations to make this happen.Have attached the screenshot below.Any help could be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

[image]